# Applescript w/Keynote. Creating build orders/Transitions for text items

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, keynote

I see documentation for creating transitions between slides but can you create from scratch build orders w/transitions?

I have a keynote presentation that's already been created and a template with a build order of 2 items but I want to be able to add more 'steps' in the build order for text that I want to add to the slide. I can access the slide just fine in my script but can't find documentation anywhere with an example of how to do this. Any ideas? thoughts?

(Using Yosemite and Keynote 6.2)

Comment: In the Keynote AppleScript dictionary :
You cannot set a transition on the text item, it's possible on the slide only.

Comment: what about if i have text items in a 'group' object? Also is there documentation where i can go to look up the limitations?

Comment: where were you looking in the dictionary where it says that?

Comment: @jackjr300 just FYI. i found a work around. You can manually create text items or groups with text items using Keynote in your slide and just put template text inside of there. After that you can set up transitions/effects for each one. Then in your applescript you can loop through the groups on the slide or text items and set the text of each to something more meaningful and the ones that dont need data you set to blank. The great thing is, the build orders/effects arent changed. :)